# How to pass data model from controller to view using JQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to get model from mcv controller in asp.net core application using JQuery.

The idea is to fill my selection options using each property of my SelectionViewModel.

It has been 2 months since I started to learn C# and asp.net application deploying, so sorry if I make a huge mistake.

Here is my cshtml view :

```
<select id="selectionContractsTypes"></select>
<select id="selectionPaymentChoices"></select>
<select id="selectionPopulationTypes"></select>

@section Scripts {

    <script>
import { forEach } from "core-js/fn/dict";

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/AjaxSelection/GetSelectionOptions",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    var selCT = $("selectionContractsTypes");
                    $(data.ContractsTypes).each(function () {
                        selCT.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
                    });

                    var selPC = $("selectionPaymentChoices");
                    $(data.PaymentChoices).each(function () {
                        selPC.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
                    });

                    var selPT = $("selectionPopulationTypes");
                    $(data.PaymentChoices).each(function () {
                        selPT.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
                    });
                    
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('eror');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Here is my SelectionViewModel class:

```
public class SelectionViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> ContractsTypes { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> PaymentChoices { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> PopulationTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my method used in ajax call:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSelectionOptions()
        {
            var model = new SelectionViewModel()
            {
                //on récup
                ContractsTypes = new ObservableCollection<string>(await _businessApiService.GetTypeContratsNamesAsync()),
                PopulationTypes = new ObservableCollection<string>(Enum.Y(typeof(X)).ToList()),
                PaymentChoices = new ObservableCollection<string>(_mockedPaymentChoices),
            };

            return Json(model);
        }
```

I have the following error :
[image]

How can I fix this?  Many Thanks :) I will appreciate your help.

Comment: For the error in the picture, remove the import. Why do you have the import if you are not using it anywhere?

Comment: Ok Borka, I have done it but I still don't get my select tag options. They are empty. No error is shown in the console :(

Comment: Can you do `console.log(data)` inside your ajax success and see if that showing values ?

Comment: Here is the result : at the begining I have nothing in the console but when I refresh the page I have this message : {contractsTypes: Array(174), paymentChoices: Array(2), populationTypes: Array(4)}

Comment: Why the console log didn't show anything when my page was loaded for 1st time?

Comment: You are missing `#` near `$("#selectionPaymentChoices")` put that for every selects .Also put your ajax code under `window.onload = function() { //your ajax code }` and see onces if that works .

Comment: Ok Swati, I should be very thiered by making small mistakes. Your 2 propositions didn't work for me. :[   Hey, I am trying to be optimistic. When I make console.log(data.ContractsTypes) I have the undefined message... I think that I sould get my key ContractsTypes using another method...

Comment: also, this code is workig but for each key I would like to use the array : 
                    var out = '<select>';
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        out += '<option>' + key + ': ' + value + '</option>';
                    });

                    out += '</select>';

                    //append out to your div
                    $("#the-return").html(out);

Comment: According to your console result i have created a working fiddle check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/emv9z6xk/) out .

Comment: Wow thanks for your example. I have red my code many times and when I used your example, I have this message error :                                                                        
    VM17 jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (site.js?v=LeANG5zEGKHV-NEHroYlmic_W4XjWI_S2viB5kNPFvA:2)
    at l (VM17 jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (VM17 jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: ok at least this one is working but it is not what I want : https://jsfiddle.net/fL5kzdhs/

Comment: your example doesn't your for me .. I fell that I am close to the sucess :)

Comment: ok I think that I have problem with my data. When I make console.log(data.PaymentChoices) => undefined resut

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224040/discussion-between-swati-and-mily).

Comment: Another question, why do you use `ObservableCollection<T>`?